# How does a generic bluetooth mouse / keyboard work with macos without installing any driver?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, bluetooth, mouse, driver

Some generic brand bluetooth keyboard / mouse work fine on macos. Does macos have a built-in common driver api (for mouse and keyboard) that all these device use or is it some specification in the Bluetooth stack that allows this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's the generic  [USB HID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) (Human Interface Device) driver/kext or [Bluetooth HID profile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles)

All operating systems have a generic HID driver  so that USB and Bluetooth keyboards, mice, and track pads will work out of the box without the need for a manufacturer supplied driver. That said, specialized keyboards and mice like those used for gaming, for example, will operate as  a generic device but, to use the  specialized functions or extra buttons, you'll need the manufacturer driver.